# Problems with XEmacs Init (init.el) on Windows 7

Tags: emacs

i was told to work on a Windows System....

Now i would like to use a mature texteditor like emacs. I downloaded and installed XEmacs (21.4.22). XEmacs ist starting, but behaves strange. It ha no org-mode, i can´t go threw the proxy to the internet, for updating or installing packaes. Therefore, i tried to configure a proxy in this Windows-Directory. XEmacs is not able to save the init-el File in the HOME-Path/.xemacs, although the file is there (XEmacs claims "no such File or Directory"). The User (me) also has permissions to save a file, i can do it with "notepad" for instance.

But i cant figure out, wat is going on, Xemacs is obviously not able to save a file in the .xemacs directory.

Comment: I found the reason for the error Message: Windows 7 in german translates also the Path Names to german (User becomes "Benutzer") but the *real* names is still in english. So, i can navigate with the FileBrowser and the german translation are displayed, but when i take those names, they are wrong, because internally, the original names are used.

Comment: Ok, but when i restart Xemacs, it still does not take the new init.el, i have to configure it somewhere else....

Comment: Unless you have a compelling reason to use XEmacs, I _strongly_ urge you to switch to [GNU Emacs](https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/emacs/windows/). XEmacs is pretty much a dead project, and has been surpassed in every way by GNU Emacs.

Comment: Thank you, Chris, i will try it tomorrow!

Comment: Also second recommendation  to switch to GNU Emacs rather than Xemacs. Make sure you get 24.5

Comment: It worked with "emacs-24.5-bin-i686-mingw32.zip" i found in a mirror in europe". Thank you!